# Python: equal axes plots with inline graphics?

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

I have just installed anaconda on a machine running Windows 7 Enterprise, 64 bit, and I'm using the ipython console within Spyder, which supports inline graphics.   I am trying to plot a sequence of points with equal axes.  According to the documentation, something like this should work:

```
import pylab
pylab.axes().set_aspect('equal')
pylab.plot(b[:,0],b[:,1],'.')
pylab.show()
```

However, any call to pylab immediately results in the creation of a figure, so with the above commands the first `pylab` call creates an empty figure (but with equal axes), and the second `pylab` call creates a new figure of the plot - but with unequal axes.  How can I get both `pylab` calls to refer to the same figure so that I end up with *one* figure containing the plot *and* with equal axes?

Answer (score 0):

In general `pylab` is [not really recommended](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#matplotlib-pyplot-and-pylab-how-are-they-related). It is better to `import pyplot` directly. Does this work for you?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

b = np.arange(20.)
b.shape = (10, 2)
b[:, 1] *= 0.2

ax = plt.subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot(b[:,0], b[:,1], '.')
ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

Setting the aspect ratio is generally one of the last operations I perform on an axes because other plotting operations often messes it up. Also note here that I have followed the 'use pyplot to create the figures and then the OO interface for plotting' guidance on [this page](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#matplotlib-pyplot-and-pylab-how-are-they-related).